# What is the maximum of the function below?

Tags: geometry, optimization, vectors, nonlinear-optimization, vector-fields

Consider the following three points:

$$\mathbf{d}_1=\mathbf{v},~~~~~~~~ \\
\mathbf{d}_2=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{e}_2,\\
\mathbf{d}_3=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{e}_3,$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ is a fixed, but arbitrary 3D vector, while $\mathbf{e}_2=(0,1,0)^{\rm T}$ and $\mathbf{e}_3=(0,0,1)^{\rm T}$.

What is the global maximum of the following function:

$$f(\mathbf{u})=\min\limits_{~i=1 \\ \mathbf{u} \ne \mathbf{d}_i}^{3}\min\limits_{~j=1 \\ ~j \ne i}^{3}\frac{|(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{d}_i)^{\rm T}(\mathbf{d}_j-\mathbf{d}_i)|}{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{d}_i\rvert\rvert\,\lvert\lvert\mathbf{d}_j-\mathbf{d}_i\rvert\rvert},$$

where $\mathbf{u}$ is the variable vector with three enetries?

**Update:**

It seems to me that this problem can be divided into four subcases:

(1) $\mathbf{u} \notin \{\mathbf{d}_1,\mathbf{d}_2,\mathbf{d}_3\}$,

(2) $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{d}_1$,

(3) $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{d}_2$, or

(4) $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{d}_3$.

Cases (2)--(4) seems to be trivial, so I would be mostly interested in case (1).

Comment: What have you tried? Is there an upper bound for this function?

Comment: @HansEngler I try to elavorate it further and post my trials within the question.

Comment: @HansEngler Could you please check my update?

Comment: Before going into cases, it may be useful to simplify the problem. What happens if you set $w = u-d$ and rewrite the problem in terms of $w$? And what are the possible values of $d_i - d_j$? And what happens if you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the denominator?

Comment: @HansEngler By the way, the geometric meaning of this problem is as follows. For each $\mathbf{u}$, I would like to find a pair $(\mathbf{d}_i,\mathbf{d}_j)$, for which the inclination angle of $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{d}_i$ and $\mathbf{d}_j-\mathbf{d}_i$, $\alpha$, is as close as $\pi/2$ as possible. The question is: if we choose $\alpha$ for each $\mathbf{u}$ in such a way, then what is the `worst' value of $\alpha$, and for which $\mathbf{u}$, where $\alpha$ is the farthest from $\pi/2$? Solving the problem numerically, it seems to me that $\pi / 4 \le \alpha \le 3 \pi / 4$.

Comment: @HansEngler It seems to me that there is more than one $\mathbf{w}$ vector, namely $\mathbf{w}_i=\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{d}_i$. What did you think of a single $\mathbf{w}$?